# Excel VBA: Larger than behaves as larger or equal

Tags: excel, vba

I use the follow code in Excel VBA:

```
If ((B - A) > 180) Then
    result = 1
ElseIf ((B - A) < -180) Then
    result = 2
Else
    result = 0
End If
```

In case (B - A) = 180, VBA returns result = 1.
The debugger shows the first statement of the If as True even if (B - A) = 180

Is it VBA acting funny or more probably me missing something?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the variable type of B and A? If it's a Single or a Double (floating point type) then this may very well explain the odd behavior. [see here for decent explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: What are the values of `A` and `B`?

Comment: `Range("A1").Value = B - A`, what do you see in cell A1? (keep out with the formatting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)